# Ember cli best way to convert xml to json

Tags: json, xml, ember.js, command-line-interface

I want to convert my xml to json so I've installed xml2json bower component but I'm not sure how to import & use in my app.

My steps were

```
bower install xml2json
```

in ember-cli-build.js I put this line before return app.toTree()

```
app.import('bower_components/xml2json/xml2json.js');
```

in app.js I have this code

```
import xml2json from 'xml2json';
```

...

```
ready: function () {
 Em.$.ajax({
  url: "/data/sequence.xml",
        dataType:"xml"
    }).done(function(xmlData){
        var jsonData = Em.$.xml2json(xmlData);
        console.dir(jsonData);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    });
}
```

I'm getting this console error:

```
Could not find module `xml2json` imported from `sequence-app/app`
```

I'm hoping it's something simple I've missed, can anyone outline what the process should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml2json.js simply creates a global, xml2json. You won't be able to import it without writing a shim.

The easiest thing to do is just use the global. Don't import it.

```
// in some route

model() {
  return Em.$.ajax({
    url: "/data/sequence.xml",
    dataType:"xml"
  }).done(function(xmlData){
      var jsonData = xml2json.xml_to_object(xmlData);
      console.dir(jsonData);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
      return jsonData;
  });
}
```

For more information read the source code of the bower component:
https://github.com/ron-liu/xml2json/blob/master/xml2json.js

If you would really prefer to use an import, just create the following shim:

```
// vendor/xmltojson.js

define('xmltojson', [], function() {
  'use strict';

  return {default: window.xmltojson};
});
```

and app.import("vendor/xmltojson") in your ember-cli-build.js